# Background drawable doesn't match its size with its parent layout

Tags: android

I am having troubles applying background color onto a list item layout. I am doing a sample app to learn android.  My problem is that it shows the colored background, but it is not the size of the list item layout. Its a bit small. Its not working for some reasons, every one here suggested to set a background drawable, set it like this:

```
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_green);
```

I am doing this inside `CursorAdapter.bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)`. Because of course I am dealing with list. Each item has a corresponding color data that I need to reflect on each list item. I need to do this programmatically. Since I must allow my self to change the background color as I please.

It looks like this:

[image]

My drawable resources like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#FFFFCC" />

</shape>
```

And this is how my list item layout looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_margin="5sp"
    android:background="@drawable/note_style"
    android:padding="5sp"
    android:paddingLeft="10sp"
    android:paddingRight="10sp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_note_short"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:maxLength="18"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@string/text_sample_short_note"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_note_remind_every"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textview_note_short"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/textview_note_short"
        android:layout_below="@id/textview_note_short"
        android:text="@string/text_sample_remind_every"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_note_date_created"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/textview_note_short"
        android:text="@string/text_sample_date"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_note_notification_alarm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textview_note_remind_every"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/textview_note_date_created"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/textview_note_date_created"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_past_due"
        android:maxHeight="20dp"
        android:maxWidth="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_alarm" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_note_notification_due"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/imageview_note_notification_alarm"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageview_note_notification_alarm"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/imageview_note_notification_alarm"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_past_due"
        android:maxHeight="20dp"
        android:maxWidth="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_due" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It does change the background color at whim but, as you can see on the picture, the green background doesn't hit the edges of layout which should match the width of the screen and height-wrap its content.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: why are you using `sp` for the padding ?

Comment: Not sure why you would need the drawable if you just want the background to be a certain color. In your `RelativeLayout` block in your list item XML, put in `android:background="#FFFFCC"`. Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: No I wanted to do it programmatically.

Comment: @Blackbelt oops, I'll change it. But I think that doesn't contribute to the problem at all.

Comment: I agree with you about that.

Comment: did you just try `setBackgroundColor` ?

Comment: Hey @pskink it works!!! Thank you! but there is problem. Setting background color is always color gray. I have yet to figure out why is this so. I am using API15+ by the way..

Comment: what gray? when you use for example setBackgroundColor(Color.RED) ?

Comment: Yes it works now. Thank you!